LilyPond Not Playing Back Accidentals?
I'm trying to play back a midi file, but the playback doesn't have any sharps or flats. How can I fix this?
I added the key signature to the midi block and the staves, but there was no difference. Is there no way to play back accidentals?

Please give some example of what you are doing. Are you perhaps just adding a key signature, but not entering the notes with alteration? E.g. \key c\minor e instead of \key c\minor ees?

I'm entering \key cis \minor in the midi { } block, upon compiling, the audio playback doesn't play with any sharps.

I think a minimal reproducible example is in order here.  See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

@t_t But \key should not matter for the midi block. It is only relevant for visuals, which is why I’m asking for some example code. So are you entering say { c d e f g } or {cis dis e fis gis}? The latter one would be correct.

We need a minimal example. \key is aesthetitcs only and there's very little point in putting it into the \midi block -- it simply doesn't do anything w.r.t. what the midi will play. The pitch of the notes doesn't care about the key signature!

I think you’re misunderstanding how key signatures and accidentals work in LilyPond.  But without any code, it’s hard to explain how fix this.  So, I’m closing this question for now — add some code (a minimal working example) and it can be reopened.
